# Echo Value of Option next to dropdown box

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo the value of a selected option next to the dropdown box and wondering if anyone could help me do it.

I've attached an image to show you what i mean.

http://postimg.org/image/6rrtj2knx/

Comment: can your post your code

Comment: <select><option value="000 000 001">Birmingham></select>

Comment: your full code. adding a select markup doesn't help anyone answer your question

Comment: That's my full code atm, I don't know how to do it

Comment: where you need to echo it?, in database (insert it)? or in a script(do things with the value)?or in another select(just show it)? i can help you but you need to express the question with more context.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrt9j63e/

Comment: Cheers All, @Steve you've done it for me though, thank you. That's me out of here to the pub

Comment: @maytham My communication is fine

Answer (score 3):

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('box').innerHTML=this.value;">
<option value="000 000 001">Birmingham</option>
</select>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you need it to an alert...
this is what you got

```
        <select id="myid"> 
            <option value="000 000 001">Birmingham </option>
        </select>
```

first you need to give your select and ID, like this :

```
       <select id="myid" ><option value="000 000 001">Birmingham></select>
```

then you need to create script that gets the value of that select

```
       <script>
         function getvalue() {
         value = document.getElementById("myid").value;
         alert(value);
         }
       </script>
```

that must be declared on the head, finally if you want to see the alert add a button that calls the function...

```
       <button onclick="getvalue()">show id</button>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/4cyafogx/

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for it to appear on the page as text?